# iPhone:Connection delegates not called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, nsurlconnection

In my app,everything works fine when run for first time.When I navigate through other views and went back to the same view,I used `viewwillappear` to call functions.

On this run,the connection request line gets executed but the connection delegates like `didReceiveResponse,didreceivedata,didfinishloading,didFailWithError` are not being called.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self recentOrderselection];
    [self recentOrderStatus];

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.tableview reloadData];

}


-(void)recentOrderStatus{

 ..................

        NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[json1 UTF8String] length:[json1 length]];

        [request setValue:@"text/plain" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

        [request setHTTPBody: requestData];

        connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

        NSLog(@"URL>>>%@",url);//Got correct URL in log

}
```

Comment: You should always put [super viewWillAppear:animated]; at first line

Comment: i hope you do have the [conection start]; statement at the end since you say it gets fired

Comment: is `viewWillAppear:` being called?

Comment: @lukya I added [connection start] at the end.Still the delegates are uncalled.

Comment: @HelmiB No, 'viewWillAppear:' is not called externally

Comment: no, i meant, if `viewWillAppear` is actually run. can you try put `NSLog` and see if it shows.

Answer (score 0):

You should always put [super viewWillAppear:animated]; at first line
And check whether the viewWillAppear function is called when you came back to same view

Comment: Yes,viewWillAppear function is called when you came back to same view.No problem there,but when came back like this the connection delegates are being called

Comment: are you releasing the conenction object in delegate method?
If not then release the connection object in delegate methoddidfinishloading,didFailWithError